# Receive JSON via POST?

Tags: php, json, callback, payment, bitcoin

I have a JSON POST request being sent to my server.

It looks like this

```
{
"order": {
    "id": "5RTQNACF",
    "created_at": "2012-12-09T21:23:41-08:00",
    "status": "completed",
    "total_btc": {
        "cents": 100000000,
        "currency_iso": "BTC"
    },
    "total_native": {
        "cents": 1253,
        "currency_iso": "USD"
    },
    "custom": "order1234",
    "receive_address": "1NhwPYPgoPwr5hynRAsto5ZgEcw1LzM3My",
    "button": {
        "type": "buy_now",
        "name": "Alpaca Socks",
        "description": "The ultimate in lightweight footwear",
        "id": "5d37a3b61914d6d0ad15b5135d80c19f"
    },
    "transaction": {
        "id": "514f18b7a5ea3d630a00000f",
        "hash": "4a5e1e4baab89f3a32518a88c31bc87f618f76673e2cc77ab2127b7afdeda33b",
        "confirmations": 0
    }
}
}
```

How can I retrieve the value of "cents" or any other variable?

Comment: `$_POST['order']['total_native']['cents']`?

Comment: Maybe take a look at `json_decode(,true)`

Comment: Use json_decode($response)- and you will have all in array form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decode it with `json_decode()` like this

```
$json = json_decode($jsonString);
```

That will give you an object and then you can use it like this

```
 echo $json->order->total_btc->cents;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
// let
$jsondata='{order:{...}}';
$json = json_decode($jsondata,true);
echo $json['order']['total_native']['cents'];
```

Comment: json_decode returns an object, unless you pass 'true' as a second param

Answer (score 0):

Depending of how you treat the incoming datas.

As Dave Chen said, using `$_POST['order']['total_native']['cents']`, but you need to decode them before, by using `json_decode()` on the specific $_POST index.

Then, choose if you need an array or an object :

```php
$json_obj = json_decode($string);
```

Will return a `stdClass` object. And to get datas, use this `$json_obj->total_btc->cents`

However, this :

```php
$json_arr = json_decode($string, true);
```

Will return an array, where you can get values with `$json_arr['order']['total_native']['cents']`

Answer (score 0):

sending

```
$data_string = json_encode(array("customer"=>array("key"=>"val")));
$data_string = urlencode(json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("customer"=>$data_string));
```

recive it

```
$datastring = $_POST['customer'];
$data = json_decode( urldecode( $datastring));
```